# how to send data from javascript to a PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My code in js (doesn't work) to transfer data to PHP is:

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location

  }); 


  var input = results[0].geometry.location; 

 var lat = input.lat(); 
 console.log(lat); 

/*var lat =  input.lat();
var longitude = input.lng();
document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML=lat;
request.open("GET", "address.php?lat=" + lat, true);

        //var url = "address.php?lat=latitude&lng =longitude";  


//document.getElementById("wypisz").innerHTML = results[0].geometry.location.lng;

*/



$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    data: "lat=" + lat,
    url:"address.php",
    success: function(data) { console.log(data) }
})

} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
 });
```

And to get them in the PHP file :

```
if(isSet($_GET['lat'])){
    echo "param good";
} else {
    echo "incorrect";   
}
```

When I `print_r` it, it always displays empty Array.
Can you help me make this conversion work?

Here's more of my code, this is the place where I mark specific latitude and longitude:

```
 <div id="panel">
  Address :
  <input id="address" name = "address" type="textbox" value="Warszawa, Pol">

  <input type="button" value="wstaw" onclick="codeAddress()" >

</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

And here I send information to php file:

```
<input type="submit" id = "ff" value="Send information">
```

Comment: var lat =  input.lat(); console.log(lat); what it shows?

Comment: why not try json? is there a reason you want to use query string?

Comment: var lat = input.lat(); console.log(lat); shows nothing.

Comment: I want to save this string  to the database.

Comment: @mac actually you do not get anything in lat variable as mentioned by you.

Comment: Ah ,sorry console log shows latitude of place : 52.195343

Comment: Can you share more of your code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open("GET", "adress.php", true);
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) 
        return; 
    console.log(req.responseText);
};
req.send("lat=" + lat);
```

This is an extremely simplistic method though and if you want all bells and whistles in regards to error validation etc, I strongly suggest you use jquery and $.get:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "lat=" + lat,
        url:"address.php",
        success: function(data) { console.log(data) }
    })
```

Comment: I got: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'

Comment: fixed my jquery answer

Comment: Now, no error on page but still empty array in php.

Comment: how are you checking your php script output? are you using chrome/firefox developer tools?

Comment: In fact I only display print_r value, and also check Chrome console.

Comment: open the chrome developer tools and check the "network" tab to see if your GET request goes through. check the status code and make sure the request url is correct in the header section (after you select your request in the list). if you need more info on the developer tools/network tab consult its help page: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network?hl=de#network_resource_details

Comment: hm, as  U advised I look it up, but there aren't any mistakes

Comment: and you're checking the response tab of the request?

Comment: mm, now when I was chcecking Chrome tools I clicked on this lat request, and it took me to page :address.php?lat=52.1553949, where  all this convertion works, but when I send information from form by clicking submit button I go to page: address.php, where I still got empty array

Comment: judging by the code you've posted, you're already sending information to your php script when you click on the "wstaw" button (since it's calling your javascript function which makes the asynchronous call). your request payload has a parameter you need to process thru javascript ("lat"), so having another submit button in this specific context doesn't make sense as you're not submitting any actual form data. a better solution would be removing the submit button and displaying a message in the success function of your ajax request that everything has been submitted.

Comment: Yes, but I have also other data, which i load through form and this submit button. Do You have idea how to do it ?

Comment: you can extend your data object in the $.ajax call to accommodate any other parameter e.g. data. "lat=" + lat + "&param1=" + param1

Comment: Ok, im not good in ajax, but i'll try.Thanks for help. I'wouldn't get so far with this issue without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ajax call like :

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET'
url: "address.php?lat="+lat,
success:function(data){
}
});
```

Comment: I get message "incorrect", or empty array when I use print_r

Comment: Ah, and also i get : Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: are you import jQuery?

Comment: that's why you getting Uncaught ReferenceError:

Comment: That's true, when I added jQuery I didn't get error. But unfortunately it still displays "incorrect" or empty Array.